# Boolean function : approximation by a linear function

Tags: co.combinatorics, oc.optimization-and-control, computer-science, np

Let $f$ be a balanced Boolean function.

> Are there $g$ linear functions, with $$\frac1{2^n}\mathrm{card} \big(\big\{\mathrm{sign} (g (x)) = 2f (x) -1, x \in \{0,1\}^n\big\}\big) > 0.55\quad ?$$

$g (x) = a_1 (2x_1-1) + ... + a_n (2x_n-1)$ and the $a_i$ reals.

Ps : if the answer is yes, then NP=P.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question as it is stated. Are you asking whether for any subset $A\subset\{-1,1\}^n$ with $|A|=2^{n-1}$ there is a half-space $P:=\{x\in\{-1,1\}^n \colon L(x)>0\}$, where $L$ is a linear, homogeneous, $n$-variate polynomial, such that $A$ has at least $51\%$ of its points inside $P$?

Comment: Yes, we can rephrase the question like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. In fact, noise sensitive functions are characterized by being asymptotically uncorrelated with all weighted majority functions.
See Theorem 1.7 in [1]. A simple example of a noise sensitive function is the xor  of all the Boolean variables. A more interesting example is percolation, see section 4 of [1].

[1] Benjamini, Itai, Gil Kalai, and Oded Schramm. "Noise sensitivity of Boolean functions and applications to percolation." Publications Mathématiques de l'Institut des Hautes Études Scientifiques 90, no. 1 (1999): 5-43. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02698830.pdf

Comment: Can you explain why the xor is a contre example?

Comment: @Dattier  The XOR function is noise sensitive (since the value of the function is  uncorrelated with its value after replacing one variable with a random bit) so Theorem 1.7 in [1] yields the claim.